# Json Array Data inserting Null Values in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Json Array Data inserting Null Values in php. Hello, I have this Json array data that i wants to insert into database. Everything works fine except that the message body/ content is inserting Null values

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [date] => 1435697125 
        [folders] => Array ( 
            [0] => \Important 
            [1] => INBOX 
            [2] => \Inbox 
            [3] => [Gmail]/Important 
        ) 
        [addresses] => Array ( 
            [from] => Array ( 
                [email] => chine@gmail.com 
                [name] => chinelo Goodman  
            ) 
            [to] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [email] => mic@gmail.com 
                    [name] => michael noway 
                ) 
             ) 
         ) 
         [sources] => Array ( 
             [0] => Array ( 
                 [label] => mic::gmail
                 [resource_url] => http://myserver.com 
             ) 
         ) 
         [subject] => Re: Testing of Data 
         [references] => Array ( 
             [0] => 
             [1] => 
             [2] => 
         ) 
         [in_reply_to] => 
         [id1] => 55930 
         [id2] => 
         [id3] => 14e46 
         [thread_id] => 14e45 
         [person_info] => Array ( 
             [chine@gmail.com] => Array ( 
                 [thumbnail] => http://localhost/contact.png 
             )
             [mic@gmail.com] => Array ( 
                 [thumbnail] => https://localhost/mic.png 
             ) 
         ) 
         [date_received] => 1435697125 
         [date_indexed] => 1435697307 
         [body] => Array ( 
             [0] => Array ( 
                 [type] => text/plain 
                 [charset] => utf-8 
                 [content] => 
                     Thank You. I hope to hear from you sooneer On 
                     Tue, Jun 30, 2015 at 1:25 PM, mic wrote: > 
                     ssfddfd dgffgff fhfghhf ffhhfhhhg ghghg > > On
                     Tue, Jun 30, 2015 at 12:41 PM, mic > wrote: > >>
                     i see it >> >> On Tue, Jun 30, 2015 at 12:38 PM,
                     chinelo > > wrote: >> >>> my message is here >>> 
                     Testing going on >>> >> >> > 
                 [body_section] => 1 
             )
```

This is how my insert statement looks like

```
foreach ($result as $value) {

}

$statement= $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO 
        json_table(
            date_received,
            date_indexed,
            message_content
        )
        values (
            :date_received,
            :date_indexed,:message_content)
');

$statement->execute(
    array( 
       ':date_received' => $value['date_received'],
       ':date_indexed' => $value['date_indexed'],
       ':message_content' => $value['addresses']['body'][0]['type']['charset']['content']
    )
);
```

Here `date_recieved` and `date_indexed` gets inserted while `message_content` keeps inserting `NULL` or empty data.
how can i insert the message content/ body into database.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you have closed your foreach loop earlier than expected

Comment: foreach loop closed is not the issue. the problem i guess lies in the order of $value arrangements that makes insertion to message_content column in the database. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are wrong ...

```
$statement->execute(array( 
':date_received' => $value[0]['date_received'],
':date_indexed' => $value[0]['date_indexed'],
':message_content' => $value[0]['body'][0]['content']
));
```

And your dump seem to be missing 3 closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have

':message_content' => $value['addresses']['body'][0]['type']['charset']['content']

Type, charset and content are different elements on the same level, you just want this

':message_content' => $value['addresses']['body'][0]['content']

Comment: Acutally body is not a child of addresses, so this is also wrong. :) You also forgot the initial index 0...

Comment: My bad. Was hard to tell with the way it was formatted. It's been fixed now just in time to make me look daft :)